# Fatal Error Installing libsndfile on OS X Mavericks

Tags: c, libsndfile

I'm currently trying to install libsndfile on my mac running os x 10.9.1.  However, when after running the command 'make' it runs for a while and then displays the following message: `sndfile-play.c:61:11: fatal error: 'Carbon.h' file not found.` I haven't had much luck finding people with a similar issue.  From what I found it looks like it may have to do with newer os versions not being supported.  Anyone know how to resolve this issue?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use brew to install it : http://brew.sh/

Once installed simply run `brew install libsndfile`

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me (I am running OS X 10.9.1):

1. Download the source code
2. Untar the bundle
3. $ ./configure
4. $ make
5. A problem should occur with Carbon.h (sndfile-play.c:61:21:
   error:    Carbon.h: No such file or directory)
6. Search Carbon.h in your machine using: $ find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ | grep Carbon.h
7. Edit **programs/**Makefile
8. Look for CFLAGS, ensure CFLAGS is configured:
   CFLAGS =
   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/    -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -funsigned-char -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -pipe -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon
9. $ make
10. $ make check (All test should pass), then:
11. $ sudo make install

Source: http://comunidad.udistrital.edu.co/ocala/2013/06/09/building-libsndfile-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: if anyone else was unclear for a moment... in the `CFLAGS` section above (Step 8), @martinweiss is suggesting you append `-I` followed by the output from `find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ | grep Carbon.h` - WITHOUT the `Carbon.h` snippet... that is, it should be the directory containing `Carbon.h`

Answer (score 2):

Also just removing that #include works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To solve in a general way (i.e. without resorting to hacking the Makefile), do an "export CPPFLAGS='-I/" with the path to your Xcode's header directory containing Carbon.h before running ./configure. Here are the steps, all from a Terminal window:

Look for instances of Carbon.h on your system:

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ | grep Carbon.h
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon/Carbon.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Carbon.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Carbon.h
```

Using the first line (because it appears to be the most generic header directory), copy the path without including Carbon.h at the end:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/
```

Finally, paste that contents within the export line (being sure to include the apostrophes at both ends of the path) like this:

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/'
```

Now re-run your ./configure and make lines to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this method (using Mac OSX 10.9.2):

1) Select the Terminal application.
2) Make sure I'm in the bash shell (method fails in csh or tcsh).
3) In response to bash$ type 
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
****** note: this brings brew in from the web. you'll have to give your
       sysadmin password*****.
4) In response to bash$ type
     "brew install libsndfile"
****** note: this brings sndfile.h and various other libsndfile files in from 
       the web and installs them in subdirectories of /usr/local . Again, you'll
       have to give your sysadmin password*****.